# How to make a Nexus proxy site into a Nexus hosted site?

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I'm using the free version of Nexus.  Currently, I have a few proxy sites that I would like to make into a local hosted site.  I have the space to download the proxied sites, but I don't have a procedure on how to do this.

Are there instructions on how to do this or can someone point to the instructions?

Comment: Is this Nexus 2 or Nexus 3?

Comment: Currently running Sonatype Nexus 2.2-01.

Comment: Do you want to copy the already downloaded artifacts from the proxy repository to the hosted repository or do you want to download the _whole_ proxy repository?

Comment: Let's go for the whole proxy repository.

Comment: I don't know any Maven mechanism for this. Furthermore, I doubt that it is a huge advantage to download a whole repository in advance. And BTW, don't try to download MavenCentral...